# Parsing my string to int is causing ValueError in python

Tags: python

For some reason int(str) is causing an error. I can't work out why. I'm wondering if someone can tell me why.

```
cx4_list_reduce = ['[#1]',(1,3,5),(7,6,9)]
list2= ['[#2]',(2,5,4), (1,3,5), (5,8,1), (7,2,6)]
n2 =3
for process_tuple in cx4_list_reduce:
      d_num = ""
      if process_tuple == list2[0]:
            d_num = process_tuple[2:3]
      n1 = int(d_num)
      if n1 <= n2:
           print('n1 =< n2')
           continue
      else:
            print('n1 => n2')
```

Error: `invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look closely at the condition:

```
d_num = ""
if process_tuple == list2[0]:
    d_num = process_tuple[2:3]
```

So what should happen when the `if` test is `False` (when the value is not equal to `list2[0]`? `d_num` remains an empty string and you cannot convert that to an integer.

The error message tells you exactly that; `invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` tells you an empty string cannot be converted.

Your first value in the `cx4_list_reduce` list is `'[#1]'`, and that string is not equal to `list2[0]` (`'[#1]` is not equal to `'[#2]'`), so the above equality test fails.

Comment: Wow, I'm impressed. I spent a whole on it.